# SQL server connecting issue

Tags: sql-server

We recently installed SQL server 2000 Std. edition on my new windows server 2003 R2 server which is the additional domain in our existing windows 2003 server domain.  Now i am unable to connect this new server from any SQL client by name of that server. if we enter the IP address of that SQL server then client are able to connect database of this server.

any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Sandesh.

Answer (score 1):

Are you having any name resolution issues?  What happens if you ping the computer name?

Comment: There is mo name resolution issue here. if we ping the that server by name or IP we get proper response from their.

Comment: Then something very strange is happening.  SQL Server doesn't know if you are trying to connect by name or by IP (nor does any other application).  Connections are made by IP addresses after DNS name resolution has completed to a numeric TCP port (unless you are using another connection method like NetBios which still uses IP addresses or Shared Memory which can only be used for local connections).  What's the exact error message that the users are receiving when connecting?

Answer (score 0):

Run the SQL Client Network Utility on a client's workstation and add an alias.

Change the net-library to use TCP-IP, and enter the name of the server and the server's IP address.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add an alias to get it working.

Comment: @mrdenny: You shouldn't, but my guess is that the OP has no internal name resolution mechanism (as you alluded to) and setting up an alias is probably the quickest, easiest solution.

Comment: Great, Well after adding server name in Configuration tool-SQL server configuration manager-SQL native client configuration-Aliases-New Alias. It's connecting by IP as well as By server name. Just need to know I am using SQL 2005 & some of the user's having SQL 2008 ver. is their the same setting need to to be done by same way or their is any other things to do.  by the way i'll try this things on SQL 2008 myself & if any issues will let you know.                                         Thanks Dan for your valued inputs here.

Comment: It's not working on SQL 2008 R2 Edition. still it's not connecting by server name.

Comment: If you have to add an alias to every machine on your network you've got some other sort of issue that needs to be addressed as there shouldn't be any need to configure an alias on every computer.